Simulation of the gyroscopic effect in SolidWorks Motion
Has anyone tried to simulate the gyroscopic effect in SolidWorks Motion?  Is the effect reproducible?
Share your knowledge and experience, please.
EDIT:
I was trying to get something like this.
https://youtu.be/ug13oUipEyA?si=UJ6mRRdA9GbNBnwx&t=105
And something like this happened. Tell me, is this the same thing?

